# regex match and remove strings like `\color{*}` in PHP

Tags: regex

That string

```
\[\color{Blue}{4} \times 2 \times 5 \times \color{Blue}{25} = \underbrace{\color{Blue}{4} \times \color{Blue}{25}}_{100} \times 5 \times 2 = \underbrace{100 \times 5}_{500} \times 2 = 500 \times 2 = 1\ 000\]
```

I want to match and remove strings like `\color{*}` in PHP

`\color` AND the next `{}` AND its content:

- \color{Blue}
- \color{Red}
- etc.

I think I am not very far...
https://regex101.com/r/gM1uW3/1

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: try **[this](https://regex101.com/r/gM1uW3/2)**

Comment: What's your expected result string?

Comment: @rock321987 thank you very much, exactly I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all `\color` commands (is this `Latex` ?), you could get along with:

```
\\color\S+
# look for \\color literally
# followed by at least one (but unlimited times)
# a non-whitespace character
```

See your [**modified demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gM1uW3/4).

Answer (score 0):

*Solution from OP.*

Found solution:

```
preg_match_all('/\\\color\{(.*?)\}/', $latex, $matches);

if (!empty($matches[0])) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $r) {
        $latex = str_replace($r, '', $latex);
    }
}
```